# Sending jpg as attachment via php

Tags: php, email

I'm using mail() of php for sending mail from my server. I want to send a jpg as attachment but I always receive a 0 lenght file. I'm stuck on it.

function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

```
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);

    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // Basic headers
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">".$eol;
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto.$eol;
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";

    // Put everything else in $message
    $message = "--".$uid.$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $message .= $message.$eol;
    $message .= "--".$uid."--".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; file=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $message .= $content.$eol;
    $message .= "--".$uid."--".$eol;

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header))
    {
        echo "mail_success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "mail_error";
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

Comment: And how do you expect us to help with your code if you do not post that code or the relevant sections of your code?

Comment: @arkascha, this is the first time that I post here.

Comment: @Jeff, my problem is with jpeg. Now I post my code.